# Outlining API to online map?

Tags: web-mapping, software-recommendations

I've had a search online and still a bit confused.

Would someone be able to outline a summary of the basic configuration of exposing data to an online map from an API?

The API supports a REST model for accessing a set of resources through a fixed set of operations. These resources includes things like:

- GridMapSquareResource
- TaxonDatasetResource
- DatasetResource

And many more.

What is the best method to use so that if I build a map application online I can then harvest this data to show on the map?

The map would work so that I could specify a particular extent on the map which would then give me the resources / data back from the API?

Comment: You need to specify very clearly what type of data you are referring to, what format the Api delivers in, what platform you are using and what you want to do with the data. Examples and links go a long way in getting answers to your questions ..

Comment: Which Mapping API?

Answer (score 2):

This information is limited, so I'm going to assume you're talking about point data.

If you control the API and want to keep it RESTFUL then you should add an additional mime type "application/vnd.geo+json" which returns [geojson](http://geojson.org/).

I'm guessing by the name of the resource GridMapSquareResource that is can except a bounding box and only return points within that box, so you would query that, the GeoJSON back and pass it to a JavaScript mapping library like Leaflet:

[Using GeoJSON with Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html)

If you're dealing with more than 10,000 points then you are going to have to start thinking about server side clustering of the points and also setting up some event hooks in Leaflet that updates the points displayed when the map is panned/zoomed.

Like I said you didn't give many details but hopefully that's enough info to get you to the next step.